# Can't convert null or undefined with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, state

I have a state that I set with Hooks in react, like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (uid !== null) {
            axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balance/${uid}`)
                .then((res) => {
                     setUserWalletIncomes(res.data[0].incomes)
                })
        }
    }, [uid])
```

This state, to be clear, give me this :
[image: Visual version]

Everything works fine I can delete my incomes etc.

**Problem** is, when I delete the last income (which makes the state empty), I have this error and a page blank :

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Here is my request to delete :

```
const handleDeleteIncome = (key) => {
        let data = { [key]: "" }
        axios({
            method: "delete",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balanceOneIncome/${uid}`,
            data: data
        }).then((res) => {
            if {(userWalletIncomes === null) setUserWalletIncomes({})}
            setUserWalletIncomes(res.data[0].incomes)
            setformIncomes(false)
        })
    }
```

I tried to add a condition : `if {(userWalletIncomes === null) setUserWalletIncomes({})}`, but I still have the same problem.

Can someone help me with this ?

[EDIT]

My state is initialized like this :

```
const [userWalletIncomes, setUserWalletIncomes] = useState({})
```

PS : If I reload the page, everything is fine.

Comment: How are you iterating over the values in render?

Comment: I think you may have other things you can improve in your app, but for a low-resolution quick "fix" you may be able to expand your conditional to include both `null` *and* `undefined`: `if (userWalletIncomes === null || userWalletIncomes === undefined) setUserWalletIncomes({})`, or maybe just `if (!userWalletIncomes) setUserWalletIncomes({})`.  You should also `return` out of that statement then to avoid continuing to do what caused the error. Also your `{}` braces are weird around this if statement, which I am hoping is a typo.

Comment: Can you please do a console.log  on res. data?. Maybe you need to add Array.isArray(res. data) before you get the first element?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes, with ```Object.entries```

Comment: That is the issue, not the hook. Either always set to at least empty object or do conditional rendering to only use object entries when it’s at least truthy.

Comment: wait what I seen `if {(userWalletIncomes === null) setUserWalletIncomes({})}`, if is started with curly braces

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I set my state like this in the beginning : ```const [userWalletIncomes, setUserWalletIncomes] = useState({})```. Is it ok ?

Comment: @Sam the console.log returns this if it still data : ```{'test': 100}``` and ```undefined``` if there is no data left

Comment: your data is not an array, but you are trying to get the first element, that is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer, if it helps someone, is this :

```
const handleDeleteIncome = (key) => {
        let data = { [key]: "" }
        axios({
            method: "delete",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balanceOneIncome/${uid}`,
            data: data
        }).then((res) => {
            if (res.data[0].incomes) {
                setUserWalletIncomes(res.data[0].incomes)
            } else {
                setUserWalletIncomes({})
            }
        })
    }
```

Just a condition that tells if response is null, then set the state to an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem? (I am assuming you don't really have the weird {} brace positioning as in your post?)

You have this:

```
if (userWalletIncomes === null) { setUserWalletIncomes({}) }
setUserWalletIncomes(res.data[0].incomes)
```

But after you call `setUserWalletIncomes({})` you fall through and immediately call it again with the null value in the next line.  Maybe you just need to explicitly return after setting it to the empty object?  Or, to simplify, you could remove that conditional and do this instead:

```
setUserWalletIncomes(res.data[0].incomes || {})
```

Comment: I found the solution, it is not far from your advice. Thank you very much :)